# Drop down values and php

Tags: php

I have a drop down menu/list in a html page. These contain links as values and labels..

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label>mylinks
  <select name="select">
    <option value="a.html">a</option>
    <option value="b.html">b</option>
    <option value="c.html">c</option>
  </select>
  </label>
```

I am trying to find a way how to get these links out of the form and in to the php page like
$a = a
$b =  b and so on , so i can use it as an external link out of the drop down in a hidden page for checking my links if working or not.
These links change from time to time..

The form contains 3 values. a.html, b.html and c.html. if I have this page opened and can select one of three I go to a page.
But I would like to have a place in this page that will echo the results of all 3 values out of the drop down as:

```
// This is not code. This is to show what I need
if value1 is <option value="a.html">a</option> then 
echo '<a href=' .value1.'>a</a>';
so i could have result at the bottom

//This is the result
<a href="a.html">a</a>
<a href="b.html">b</a>
<a href="c.html">c</a>
```

My problem is how to extract the values from the form and echo them as href. Is there a way with php or do I have to do a function or something else? Hope this helped.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @Kostas. Your question is very hard to understand. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: You access the selected value with `$_POST['select']` after submission. If this isn't what you meant, your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example, (it works as I understood to your question)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Kostas Example</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="form1" action="" method="post">
        <label>My Links</label>
        <select name="select">
            <option value="a.html">Document a</option>
            <option value="b.html">Document b</option>
            <option value="c.html">Document c</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <?php 

        if(isset($_POST['select'])) {
            $link = $_POST['select'];
            echo "<a href='$link'>Document " . $link . "</a>";
        }

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works fine. But we get the result "Document a.html" after we submit . And only that document. I need the link as drop down as it is as also as all other document links before submiting. I have tried to make an array with all words of the dropdown code.  and I have this result.

Comment: Array ( [0] => form [1] => name [2] => form [3] => method [4] => post [5] => action [6] => label [7] => my [8] => links [9] => select [10] => name [11] => select [12] => option [13] => value [14] => a [15] => html [16] => a [17] => option [18] => option [19] => value [20] => b [21] => html [22] => b [23] => option [24] => option [25] => value [26] => c [27] => html [28] => c [29] => option [30] => select [31] => label )

Comment: hen I tried to compare each word with "value"  .


But I stacked here because I receive a result number 13 that is the first value result but after this I have two more at place 19 and 25. If I bypass this problem it might be easy to echo place 19 + 1 = "a" and place 19 +2 = "html". but I am new here and my logic might be wrong..

Comment: as you see in place 14 + "." + 15 we have the link. As it is in 20+"."+ 21 and also 26+ "."+ 27. So here I need a foreach logical.

Answer (score 0):

This in not an answer. Just were I am. I entered the string of first html so it can be easier to work on...

```
 <?php

$html = '<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label>my_links
  <select name="select">
    <option value="a.html">a</option>
    <option value="b.html">b</option>
    <option value="c.html">c</option>
  </select>
  </label>';
echo $html;
$html2 = str_word_count($html, 1);
print_r($html2);
$count = 0;
foreach ($html2 as $value[$count]){
$count = $count + 1 ;
print $count."<br>";
//print "<br>";
$match_index = array_search("value", $value);
echo $match_index;
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of search on the internet I came to an answer for this problem.
This is the code

```
 <?php

$html = '<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label>my_links
  <select name="select">
    <option value="a.html">a</option>
    <option value="b.html">b</option>
    <option value="c.html">c</option>
  </select>
  </label>';
echo $html;
echo "<br>";
$html2 = str_word_count($html, 1);
//print_r($html2);
$count = 0;
foreach ($html2 as $value){
$a[$count] = $html2;
//echo a[$count];
$match_index = array_search("value", $html2[$count]);
//echo $match_index;
$count = $count + 1 ;
//print $count."<br>";
}
//print "my result = ".$count."<br>";
foreach(range(0, $count) as $num){
    if ("value" == $html2[$num]){
    $a = $html2[$num +1];
    $b = $html2[$num + 2];
    echo '<a href="'.$a. '.'. $b .'">'. $a .'<br>';
    }else{
    echo "";
    }
}
?>
```

There are a problem here.
If my link has two or more word separated with a space then I will not have in the end ".html" as I expect but ".second word". Not good.
I am sure that code like this exist but I haven't found it yet. If anyone has an idea please add a comment..

Comment: I found out that I had onme more problem. If the link had number in it it would not show in the array. And all special charactervs would not be displayed. like "/ () " ext. So if a link is in another folder there is a problem. Like  html://www.home.com/my_link123.html shows as httml , www, home , com, my , html . so link and 123 are lost